# How to redirect to the Auth0 login page automatically, when the application URL is typed in the browser

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, auth0, angular-auth-oidc-client

To configure the application login URI in Auth0 for Single Page Application in angular. To redirect to the Auth0 login page automatically, when the application URL is typed in the browser. Instead of triggering the Login page from browser via button or some other action.

When I'm trying I'm getting angular application login page and then auth0 login page is coming. But I want only auth0 login page.

Comment: Please share some code to show us what you have done

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.